How can I get newly inserted devices to get recognized by ls (directory listing)?
I use Arch Linux and I find that if I plug a USB drive into my computer then it does not show up in /run/media/user-name. However, if I use caja I can see the drive and view its contents. Then if I go back to the command line, and run ls /run/media/user-name it shows up.
Is this because caja is mounting the drive or something? How can I easily do this from the command line? I mean I know how to mount things, but it is a pain in the ass because you have to look up the device name, etc etc. Is there an easy way to just get a device recognized (other than just looking at it in caja)?


Is this becasue caja is mounting the drive or something?

caja asks your system for the thing to be mounted, yes.

How can easily do this from the command line.

udisksctl mount -b /dev/something if you already know the storage device name. If not, you can easily find out what the newest device is that appeared, ls -lt /dev/block/ will give you the newest first.
You can unmount using udisksctl unmount -b /dev/something.
What the the desktop environment does differently than this is that it has a daemon that actively listens for the events exchanged in your system when a new USB device is plugged in, so that this detection step happens in the background, and the device appears in caja automatically. It is mounted by udisks on request by caja, the moment you click on it (not earlier).
You can build yourself a neat little helper around that same functionality that caja uses, so you can mount things from the terminal, with this zsh script I wrote for you:
#!/usr/bin/zsh
# Copyright 2024 Marcus Müller
# Licensed under EUPL-1.2
# 
# Script to show all block devices added the last 10 minutes
# Needs ZSH to be installed.

#                        /---- (…): "glob specifier"
#                        |/---   N: don't error if there's NO matching device
#                        ||
#                        ||  /--  c: created since…
#                        |/  |/-  m: in minutes
#                        |   |/ -10: the last ten
#                        |   |
#                        |   | /- oc: order by creation date
#                        |   | |
#                        |   | | 
#                        vvvvvvvv
newdevices=(/dev/block/*(Ncm-10oc))
counter=1
now=$(date +%s)
for dev in $newdevices; do
  creation=$(stat -c %W "${dev}")
  age=$((now-creation))
  age_minutes=$(( age/60 ))
  age_second=$(( age%60 ))
  printf '%d) %s (%d:%d)\n' $counter "$(basename "$(readlink -f "${dev}")")" $age_minutes $age_seconds
  counter=$((counter+1))
done
printf 'q) quit\nwhat? '

read choice
printf 'chose %d\n' "$choice"
[[ "$choice" = q ]] && exit
if ! [[ "$choice" =~ '^[0-9]+$' ]]; then
  printf 'Invalid number; quitting without action'
  exit 1
fi

choice=$(( choice )) #convert to integer
if [[ $choice -gt ${#newdevices} ]]; then
  printf 'choice %d larger than new devices (%d). Aborting.\n' $choice ${#newdevices}
  exit 2
fi

device="${newdevices[${choice}]}"
printf "Requesting to mount %s…\n" "${device}"
udisksctl mount -b "$(readlink -f "${device}")"

copy and paste into a text file, save somewhere as "pluggables", chmod 755 /path/to/pluggables to make it executable. Then run as /path/to/pluggables.

Just mentioning pmount as another alternative for mouting without root access.

@FelixJN right, there were a number of competing standards on how to do user mounting in the olden times. However, since caja works for the asker, I'd recommend he sticks with something that uses the same policy/mounting framework, not add another one to the mix.
